# Lua level formula

Tags: math, lua, formula

I'm trying to calculate a players level depending on the players experience.

This is what I have in text:
Start at level 0 with 0 XP
To reach level 1, you need 50 XP.
One kill gives 10 XP.
So, 5 kills = 50 XP = level 1.
Now, level 2 should require 50 XP more than last level.
So, level 2 requires a total of 150 XP.
Level 1: 50 XP (5 kills total, 5 kills to go from level 0 to 1).
Level 2: 150 XP(15 kills total, 10 kills to go from level 1 to 2).
Level 3: 300 XP(30 kills total, 15 kills to go from level 2 to 3).

So far, all I got is this:

```
math.Round( xp / 50 )
```

This is 50 xp per level which isn't what I wanted; but I have really no idea where to go from here.

Simply put, I want each level to require 50 more XP than last level, and I need to get the level from an xp variable.

Comment: `math.Round` is not a standard function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick math calculation shows that the experience point to reach level `lv` would be:

```
(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + lv) * 50
```

which equals:

```
lv * (lv + 1) / 2 * 50
```

So the question becomes to find the maximum non-negative integer `lv` that qualifies:

```
lv * (lv + 1) / 2 * 50 <= xp
```

That's the formula needs to be solved. And the math solution is:

```
lv <= (math.sqrt(xp * 4 / 25 + 1) - 1) / 2
```

Since you are looking for a non-negative integer, in the words of Lua, that's:

```
local lv = math.floor((math.sqrt(xp * 4 / 25 + 1) - 1) / 2)
```

You can wrap it to a function and give it a quick test like this:

```
function xp_to_lv(xp)
    return math.floor((math.sqrt(xp * 4 / 25 + 1) - 1) / 2)
end

assert(0 == xp_to_lv(0))
assert(0 == xp_to_lv(49))
assert(1 == xp_to_lv(50))
assert(2 == xp_to_lv(260))
assert(3 == xp_to_lv(310))
```

Comment: Thank you! I now realise that it's a bit unbalanced with this formula :P

Comment: The base behind Yu Hao's first formula is the linear sequence `xp_per_level(n) = n * 50`, you can easily replace the 50 with an inclination constant `k`. this will go through all the formulas and you end up with `lv = floor((sqrt(xp*8/k+1)-1)/2)` and then you can simply "balance" your formula by modifying `k`, unless you think the linear sequence itself is not balanced. But usually this is counteracted by the player receiving more XP for tasks at higher levels.